# AccessDeniedException in java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I'm developing a security mechanism to my project in java where I use AccessDeniedException to restrict access to users in some methods of project. I work with ws to publish this methods. I use tomcat 7 to deploy my ws. Now when I startup tomcat 7 to deploy my ws this is that show in console of my IDE Eclipse:

```
GRAVE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/AccessDeniedExceptionjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:545)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:223)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 16 more
```

I use jre7 although I have imported jre6 and jre8 to my project too. I have imported java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException class in my code. I don't understand what is happened in this case. Is how if my project not found java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException class. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` is a new class as of Java 7. Smells to me like your setup is confused and is actually using Java 6. May I ask why you have three JREs imported to your project?

Comment: You can only compile against one jre at a time. Remove jre6 (backwards compatible) and jre8 (not compatible) if you are going for [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: I already changed my jre to version 7 only in my project and nothing has changed, the error keeps appearing in console. I was searching for a solution and I ask if exist the possibility that some library is missing in my project or Tomcat7 lib??

Comment: issue solved!!! In the setup of my tomcat7 I had configured that it work with jre6 version and I changed it to jre7 and it works.